# Git push hangs up leading to internet problems

Tags: git, github

The scenario is like this:

I have android source code (aosp) synced up. I want to make a "fork" of it in my repository. But since I was unable to find a way to fork just a specific branch and not the whole repo, I decided to manually push it. For this, I created a new bare repository on github.

My project has two remotes:

```
* aosp = https://android.googlesource.com/path_to_project.git
#The default remote using which I synced repo

* upstream = https://github.com/<my github user-name>/<newly created repo name>.git
#The remote I added manually
```

I tried to push it by following method:

```
#First added remote to that bare repository
git remote add upstream https://github.com/<my github user-name>/<newly created repo name>.git

#This is the branch for which I want to fork that project
git checkout -b kitkat-mr2.2-release

#I want the branch to be named kitkat in my own repo
git push -u upstream kitkat-mr2.2-release:kitkat
```

The output is as follows:

```
Counting objects: 869653, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (200676/200676), done.
Writing objects: 100% (869653/869653), 1.23 GiB | 101.65 MiB/s, done
Total 869653 (delta 582065), reused 867347 (delta 581182)
```

And then it remains there. A little web-search told me that its supposed to be so, so I consider its normal. But after sometime, my whole internet stops working. System Monitor still shows normal upload speed and such, but I am unable to use internet. It starts giving me this on every/any webpage:

[image]

Even any webpage I open on phone using wifi gives same result. And I have to restart my modem to get past this error/bug.

I also tried using `git config http.postBuffer 1825361101` (again, a result of web-search) before the `git push` but it doesn't help either.

Please help me solve this issue. I am fairly new to github, still trying to figure a lot of things out. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With further research into problem, I found this solution which seems to work:

```
git config --global sendpack.sideband false
```

Now git push works fine.